# Does it have any side-effects, that the JS and DOM strings are stored in UTF16?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, utf

JS and DOM strings are implemented with `UTF16` strings. What would happen, if a browser would use `UTF8` or `UTF32` strings in the background? Is there any JS code, which would run differently, and give different result?

Comment: Comparing strings will result in false-positive effect, some symbols may be displayed different than it should be

Comment: for example? Could you please provide a short example code, which would run differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low-level string operations such as `charCodeAt` would likely return different values, which is hazardous for applications that use strings like byte arrays (which is a quite common carry-over from the pre-[TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)-era). And in general, string indices would work differently for any strings containing multi-byte characters.

In order not to break the web, an implementation would therefore need to masquerade its background format as UTF16 to the JavaScript interface, which would be rather inperformant. There's no advantage to be gained either.

Comment: For example, `"".length` falsely returns `2`.